# Yii1: CGridView link ajax request shows 400 Bad Request

Tags: ajax, cgridview, yii1.x

I am working on Yii 1 application. In my application, there is a CGridView where there is a link, which also fires an ajax request on onclick event. I am sending id as parameter. But the ajax return **400 Bad Request** error. Please help me in this matter.

Here is the Gridview:

```
<h3>Civil Cases</h3>
<?php  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'notifications-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider_civil,
    'summaryText' => false,

    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'case_id',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->case_id),array("civilcases/view","id"=>$data->case_id), array("onclick"=>"js:readNotification($data->id)"))'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'caseno',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->caseno),array("civilcases/view","id"=>$data->case_id), array("onclick"=>"js:readNotification($data->id)"))'
        ),
        'date_filing',
        'next_date',
        'panel_lawyer_id',

    ),
));
?>
```

here is the script:

```
<script>
    var readNotification = function(id) {
        console.log("button clicked with ID: "+id); //getting id here
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("notifications/readNotification");?>',
            data: {id: id}
        });
    };
</script>
```

here is the controller:

```
public function actionReadNotification(){
    echo $_POST['id'];
}
```

added readNotification function to the **accessRules**. When clicking on the link new page is loading but ajax request shows error.

Comment: hey did the edit part worked for you ?

Comment: it worked for me. sorry didn't reply, I was busy on other works. I think the problem occurred because I did not send the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the csrf token inside your data with your ajax request.

```
<script>
    var readNotification = function(id) {
        console.log("button clicked with ID: "+id); //getting id here
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl("notifications/readNotification");?>',
            data: {id: id,<?= 
            Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName?>:<?=Yii::app()->request->csrfToken?>,}
        });
    };
</script>
```

You can also disable the csrftoken by adding the below in the `beforeAction()`

```
public function beforeAction($action) {

    if($action->id=='readnotification'){
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

but this is not recommended way of doing the work.

### `EDIT`

i mistakenly added `Yii::$app->request` instead of `Yii::app()->request` as the first one is for `Yii2` and not for `Yii1` please change it to

```
<?=Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName?>:<?=Yii::app()->request->csrfToken?>
```

and make sure you have the `request` component with the following configurations

```
'components'=>array(
.
.
.
    'request'=>array(
          'enableCookieValidation'=>true,
          'enableCsrfValidation'=>true,
          'csrfTokenName'=>'_my-token',
    ),
```

*Note : you can change the `_my-token` to any other name you like*

Comment: sorry for replying late and also thank you for the suggestion. I have solved that issue another way. Anyway, I will try that, and get back to you because I have to do that again

Comment: sorry man it didn't work. tried to send csrftoken but not working. it seems `\yii::$app->request->csrfParam` not working

Comment: sorry, my bad @Mislam I added the `Yii2` syntax :/ , just updated it should be `Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName` rather than `\yii::$app->request->csrfParam` see the edit part in my answer, and sorry for late reply been busy.